# How to quickly get today's close prices of all stock in SPY500?

Tags: python

I just need today's close price for all the stocks in SPY500 or QQQ. I am using `DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)`. Even getting one day's data, it is very slow. Is there a faster way to get all stock data quickly? I just like to know how many stocks are above EMA20 and what are the top 10 stocks?  Thanks

```
timenow=datetime.now()
previousday=datetime.today()-timedelta(1)
end_date = timenow.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") #"%Y-%b-%d-%b-(%H:%M:%S.%f)"
start_date=previousday.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

# open file with tickers of each comapny
close_price_today_each={}
with open("sp500tickers.pickle", "rb") as f:
    tickers = pickle.load(f)
    for ticker in tickers:
        ticker=ticker[:-1]  # /n at the end
        print('Getting close price of '+ticker)
        df = data.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start_date, end_date)
        close_price_today_each[ticker]=df['Close'].iloc[-1]
```

Comment: Which part is slow? Low hanging fruit advice: you can use `import cPickle` instead of `import pickle` to speed up the pickle loading a bit, since cPickle is implemented in C instead of in Python.

Comment: Thanks. I think data.DataReader() is slow. I tried to install cPickle. I got an error of pip install cPickle
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cPickle (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cPickle

Comment: Nowadays (python 3) the correct command is `import _pickle` or for simplicity `import _pickle as pickle`

Comment: what is the difference between import pickle and import _pickle? Thanks